# JobLauncherTestUtils throws NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException while trying to test spring batch steps

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using Spring boot and Spring batch. I have defined more than one job.

I am trying to build junit to test specific task within a job.

Therefor I am using the JobLauncherTestUtils library.

When I run my test case I always get NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {BatchConfiguration.class})
public class ProcessFileJobTest  {

    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    static class TestConfig {
        @Autowired

        private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilder;
        @Autowired
        private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilder;

        @Bean
        public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
            JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
            jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(jobUnderTest());
            return jobLauncherTestUtils;
        }


        @Bean
        public Job jobUnderTest() {
            return jobBuilder.get("job-under-test")
                    .start(processIdFileStep())
                    .build();
        }


        @Bean
        public Step processIdFileStep() {
            return stepBuilder.get("processIdFileStep")
                    .<PushItemDTO, PushItemDTO>chunk(1) //important to be one in this case to commit after every line read
                    .reader(reader(null))

                    .processor(processor(null, null, null, null))
                    .writer(writer())

                            //     .faultTolerant()
                            //   .skipLimit(10) //default is set to 0
                            //     .skip(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
                    .build();
        }


        @Bean
        @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
        public ItemStreamReader<PushItemDTO> reader(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext[filePath]}") String filePath) {
            ...
            return itemReader;
        }

        @Bean
        @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
        public ItemProcessor<PushItemDTO, PushItemDTO> processor(@Value("#{jobParameters[pushMessage]}") String pushMessage,
                                                                 @Value("#{jobParameters[jobId]}") String jobId,
                                                                 @Value("#{jobParameters[taskId]}") String taskId,
                                                                 @Value("#{jobParameters[refId]}") String refId)
        {
            return new PushItemProcessor(pushMessage,jobId,taskId,refId);
        }

        @Bean
        public LineMapper<PushItemDTO> lineMapper() {
            DefaultLineMapper<PushItemDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<PushItemDTO>();
           ...
            return lineMapper;
        }

        @Bean
        public ItemWriter writer() {
            return new someWriter();
        }
    }


    @Autowired
    protected JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;



    @Test
    public void processIdFileStepTest1() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("filePath", "C:\\etc\\files\\2015_02_02").toJobParameters();
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("processIdFileStep",jobParameters);

    }
```

and thats the exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Job] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: jobUnderTest,executeToolJob,processFileJob
```

Any idea? 
Thanks.

added BatchConfiguration class:

```
package com.mycompany.notification_processor_service.batch.config;

import com.mycompany.notification_processor_service.common.config.CommonConfiguration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


@ComponentScan("com.mycompany.notification_processor_service.batch")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Configuration
@Import({CommonConfiguration.class})
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicationContext-pushExecuterService.xml"/*,"classpath:si/integration-context.xml"*/})
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Value("${database.driver}")
    private String databaseDriver;
    @Value("${database.url}")
    private String databaseUrl;
    @Value("${database.username}")
    private String databaseUsername;
    @Value("${database.password}")
    private String databasePassword;



    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(databaseDriver);
        dataSource.setUrl(databaseUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(databaseUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

and this is CommonConfiguration

```
@ComponentScan("com.mycompany.notification_processor_service")
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mycompany.notification_processor_service.common.repository.jpa"})
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mycompany.notification_processor_service.common.repository.couchbase"})
@EntityScan({"com.mycompany.notification_processor_service"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAsync
public class CommonConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: What's in `BatchConfiguration`?

Comment: I added it to the question

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and the easier way is injecting in the setter of `JobLauncherTestUtils` like Mariusz explained in [Jira of Spring](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2366):

> ```
> @Bean
> public JobLauncherTestUtils getJobLauncherTestUtils() {
>
>     return new JobLauncherTestUtils() {
>         @Override
>         @Autowired
>         public void setJob(@Qualifier("ncsvImportJob") Job job) {
>             super.setJob(job);
>         }
>     };
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So I see the jobUnderTest bean.  Somewhere in all those imports, you're importing the two other jobs as well.  I see your `BatchConfiguration` class imports other stuff as well as you having component scanning turned on.  Carefully trace through all your configurations.  Something is picking up the definitions for those beans.

Comment: Even if I import all other beans why i cant tell implicit to the JobLauncherTestUtils  that I want to inject into it only jobUnderTest ?

Comment: Because the job in `JobLauncherTestUtils` is autowired (the setter is marked with an `@Autowired` annotation).

Comment: How would you adjust it in this case?

Comment: Who is bootstrapping `TestConfig`?  I don't see that class actually being referenced anywhere...

Comment: as soon as I start my junit test case and set it as static and with the @Configuration annotation it's starting

Comment: I saw this example somewhere.. mybe it's not the right way to do?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue and couldn't have JobLauncherTestUtils to work properly. It might be caused by [this issue](http://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2366)

I ended up autowiring the SimpleJobLauncher and my Job into the unit test, and simply

```
launcher.run(importAccountingDetailJob, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

An old post, but i thought of providing my solution as well.

In this case i am automatically registering a `JobLauncherTestUtils` per job

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    private List<Job> jobs;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerServices() {
       jobs.forEach(j->{
         JobLauncherTestUtils u = create(j);
         final String name = j.getName()+"TestUtils"
         beanFactory.registerSingleton(name,u);
           beanFactory.autowireBean(u);
           logger.info("Registered JobLauncherTestUtils {}",name);

       });

    }

    private JobLauncherTestUtils create(final Job j) {
        return new MyJobLauncherTestUtils(j);
    }

    private static class MyJobLauncherTestUtils extends JobLauncherTestUtils {


        MyJobLauncherTestUtils(Job j) {
            this.setJob(j);
        }

        @Override // to remove @Autowire from base class
        public void setJob(Job job) {
            super.setJob(job);
        }
    }
}
```