# spring-boot-batch with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-batch

this is my first post on this forum so please go easy on me if a made mistake or else. I'm using spring-boot batch with mongdb and everything works fine but I running in trouble when I have to test my batch. My Batchconfiguration is based on multiple jobs (4 jobs), so

1. **1st trouble**
   when I used JobLauncherTestUtils spring doesn't know which job to inject and I don't know how to specify that to test the jobs one by one.
2. **2nd trouble** when I separate my configuration to testing only one job, JobLauncherTestUtils couldn't been creating because it's need dataSource, as I used MongoDb with mongotemplate I don't use dataSource.

the stack error look like :

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepositoryTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Hope anybody will help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1st trouble when i used JobLauncherTestUtils spring don't know wich job to inject and i don't know how to specify that to test the jobs one by one.

You can specify which job to launch using `JobLauncherTestUtils#setJob`. Please see [JobLauncherTestUtils throws NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException while trying to test spring batch steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293266/joblaunchertestutils-throws-nouniquebeandefinitionexception-while-trying-to-test)

> 2nd trouble when I separate my configuration to testing only one job, JobLauncherTestUtils couldn't been creating because it's need dataSource, as I used MongoDb with mongotemplate I don't use dataSource.

According to the error `Error creating bean with name 'jobRepositoryTestUtils'`, it is not `JobLauncherTestUtils` that could not be created but `jobRepositoryTestUtils`. The repository test utils is a convenience class to create and remove job executions from a database (See its [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/test/JobRepositoryTestUtils.html)). So it requires a datasource. If you don't have a data source in your test context, you need to remove this bean declaration.

Comment: Thank for your reply, this link help me to solve my problem.